# C sqlite3 how to print the actual query after prepare and bind?

Tags: c, sqlite

how can I print the actual final sqlite3 query that is executed in a portion of code like this?

```
int rc;
sqlite3_stmt *res;
char *query = "";
query = "SELECT count(*) FROM `db_report` WHERE `r_sn` = ?;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &res, 0);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, sn, strlen(sn), SQLITE_STATIC);
} 
int step = sqlite3_step(res);
PRINT REAL QUERY
sqlite3_finalize(res);
return 0;
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`sqlite3_expanded_sql`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/expanded_sql.html) to retrieve a pointer to a string that contains the final query with bound parameters expanded.

Comment: Good to know. Never used but useful for debug purpose.

Comment: I used "sqlite3_sql" to retrieve the not expanded query and it works, but when I try to use "sqlite3_expanded_sql" i got "implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_expanded_sql’". I'm compiling with this command: cc -c libsqlite.c -lsqlite3

Comment: @willygroup - It was added in [V3.14](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html). Make sure you have that or newer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. :( My version is way too old (3.7.9).

Comment: This exactly answered my question as well, but alas here we are in 2019 and Redhat(7.5) is still on freakin version 3.7.17  <sigh> :(